# The type parameter is X hiding the type X

Tags: java, types, extending

I'm trying to implement this code. Rent is a subclass of Transaction.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class TransactionList<Transaction> extends LinkedList { //TransactionList: warning: The type parameter Transaction is hiding the type Transaction

public TransactionList<Rent> getRentTransactions(){
    TransactionList<Rent> rentList = new TransactionList<Rent>();

    for(Transaction t : this){ //this: error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Transaction
        if(t instanceof Rent){ 
            t = (Rent) t; //this: warning: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Rent to Transaction
            rentList.add((Rent) t);// whole statement: warning: Type safety: The method add(Object) belongs to the raw type LinkedList. References to generic type LinkedList<E> should be parameterized
        }
    }
    return rentList;
}
```

I'm really lost with this, I'm absolutely sure this code is type safe as any given TransactionList will always contain Transaction or a subclass of Transaction.

However if I change the for statement to

```
for(Object t : this)
```

it will compile. However all Objects held by the returned TransactionList will be of the type Object, and unable to be casted to Rent Objects.

Comment: Yes exactly, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You more than likely meant

```
public class TransactionList extends LinkedList<Transaction> {
```

What you had

```
public class TransactionList<Transaction> extends LinkedList {
```

declares a new type variable named `Transaction`. So it's equivalent to

```
public class TransactionList<T> extends LinkedList {
```

and the parent class declaration is raw. [Read this to understand when and when not to use raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). In this case, the type parameter that you've named `Transaction` is hiding a concrete type also named `Transaction`.

You can't do this

```
for(Transaction t : this)
```

because `this` is an `Iterable` through inheritance (`extends LinkedList`), but since it's a raw type, the type is erased to `Object`. An `Object` is not assignment compatible with the type parameter `Transaction`.

Comment: Thanks for the great clarification. I feel kinda silly now! :)